# How to store a python list and a dictionary datatype in sqlite via peewee

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I have a list in python, e.g. [2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4].
I am storing this via peewee into a sqlite table of type "Text".
When I read this from the d.b. I get a string:
"[2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4]"

If I want to iterate over the list, e.g. 
`value = model_risk[i]`
it iterates over the character because it's a string

model: [2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4]

`value from db: [
value from db: 2
value from db: ,
value from db:

value from db: 2
value from db: ,
value from db:

value from db: 4
value from db: ,`

So the questions are:
1.) How to proper store a list into sqlite via peewee ORM
2.) How to proper read a list into sqlite via peewee ORM
3.) Same questions from above for dictionary type

UPDATE:
Did it now this way:

1.) Loading strings from SQLite TEXT-columns into a python list (previously stored from a python list):
`if ra_obj.model_risk:
            model_risk = ra_obj.model_risk.strip('[]').split(', ')`

2.) Loading dictionaries from SQLite TEXT-columns into a python dict (previously stored from a python dict):

```
def dict_from_str(string) -> dict:
    """ Convert given string to a dictionary. """
    dict_ret: dict = {}

    if string:
        import json
        json_acceptable_string = string.replace("'", "\"")
        try:
            dict_ret = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            print("json decoder error")

    return dict_ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use an ArrayField type (if you are using Postgres). Or you can use a JSON type, which is supported on Sqlite > 3.9 (I think) and Postgres or a recent-ish MySQL.

You may have fundamentally missed the idea that a database table is like a spreadsheet. How do you store a list of numbers in a spreadsheet? You don't pack them all into a single cell. You normalize them.

Comment: Thx for your reply; I am aware of the database table. ;) I did it now partly via JSON type as suggested by you!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is been answered but I couldn't use the JSONField type for some compatibility reason. Neither did I unsderstand your first solution (which seemed a bit over), so here goes two simpler ways to work it around:

1 - use eval:

```
eval("[1,2,3,4]") = [1,2,3,4]
```

2 - or just use json.loads() straight foward:

```
json.loads("[1,2,3,4]")  = [1,2,3,4]
```

If I missed something on your question please let me know.